# Htaccess - redirect to folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need help with redirecting from subdomain to folder.

I've tried this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.company.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://company.com/subdomain/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

but I can't get it work.
Here is htaccess I'm working with - I'd rather not change the existing rewrite rules, so I'm putting the new rewrite condition right after RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]*)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
# maximally two redirects
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=2
# whatever domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+).([a-zA-Z0-9-]+).([a-zA-Z]+)$
# Condition to distinguish final URL - prevention of endless loop
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*)redirect=1(.*)$ [NC]
# path to file: /domain/path
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%2.%3/$1?redirect=1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Well, what does "I can't get it work" actually mean? Do you get entries in your access log file? In your error log file? Is a redirection done, but wrong? No redirection done at all? Does the universe implode?

Comment: Are you getting a redirect loop?